# Horizontal Pod Autoscalar in Spring boot Application

Tags: kubernetes

I have a spring boot application and I have created a deployment yaml file for this.
Now I have assigned it resources :

```
resources:
            requests:
              memory: "200Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "655Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
```

and I have created my autoscalar as:

```
kubectl autoscale deployment demo-app --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10
```

Now my issue is when my app starts, CPU utilization for pod reached almost 100%(during startup only for 5-10 mins and then return to normal) and hence my autoscalar creates a new pod.

But what I want is it should wait for a specific period after the startup of pod(for the readiness probe to be completed), then only it creates new pods if needed

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag  `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-cpu-initialization-period`
The readiness delay can also be introduced: `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-initial-readiness-delay` and you can use  metric loop time, `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period` to calculate the total delay.

These flags can help you set values so you can avoid problem of auto scaling during app initialization.

Read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details)

Answer (score 0):

There is a global flag `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-cpu-initialization-period` which means *The period after pod start when CPU samples might be skipped*.Default value is 5 min .You need to set this to a higher value in **kube controller manager**